# List in list (Model) Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate

I would like to create list of data in list of data. I believe this can be difficult to explain but I will try explain my problem very clear. I created list of data but in this list some arguments are also list of data. I have to write using this code because this are restriction (Our Factory). If I take data, which are not list of data, everything working correct. Where is problem? If I write list in list I get error. Perhaps you can see there my mistake.

Program is compile.

Problem(I take data from third table using mapping in NHibernate):

```
DestynationName = (List<dictionaryNewInfoSupportList>x.DictImportantInformationSDestination.Select(n=> new DictionaryNewInfoSupportList { Id = n.Destination.Id, Name = n.Destination.Desciption}).ToList();
```

DestynationName in Model

```
public Ilist<dictionaryNewInfoSupportList> DestynationName;
```

Class:

```
class dictionaryNewInfoSupportList
{
public string Name {get; set;}
public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

Important:

```
public IEnumerable<DictionaryListModel> OnList(DictionayDisplayModel dictionary DisplayModel, int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
{
var displayModel = (DictionaryNewInfoDisplayModel)dictionaryDisplayModel;
if (displayModel == null)

var list = _dictImportantInformation.GetList().Select(
x=> new DictionaryNewInfoListModel
    {
        Id = x.Id
        Description = x.Description,
        IsActiveYN = x.IsActive,
        DestynationName = (List<DictionaryNewInfoSupportList>) x.DictImportantInformationXDestination.Select(n => new DictionaryNewInfoSupportList 
        { Id = n.Destination.Id, Name = Destination.Description}).To.List()
    }
    ).ToList();

return list;

}
```

I have got answer (Topic Closed)

```
var list = _dictImportantInformation.GetList().ToList().Select(
            x => new DictionaryNewInfoListModel
                     {
                         Id = x.Id,
                         Description = x.Description,
                         IsActiveYN = x.IsActive,
                         DeestynationName = x.DictImportantInformationXDestination.Select(n => new DictionaryNewInfoSupportList 
                         { Id = n.Destination.Id, Name = n.Destination.Description }).ToList()
                     }

            ).ToList();
```

Comment: put this as answer and accept it, best way to close topic

Comment: Please follow the procedure @dove requested. This question is still showing up as unanswered - but you answered it yourself (which is fine). So click "Answer Your Own Question", add it as an answer, and in two days (I think) you'll be able to accept it as the answer and get it off the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = _dictImportantInformation.GetList().ToList().Select(
            x => new DictionaryNewInfoListModel
                     {
                         Id = x.Id,
                         Description = x.Description,
                         IsActiveYN = x.IsActive,
                         DeestynationName = x.DictImportantInformationXDestination.Select(n => new DictionaryNewInfoSupportList 
                         { Id = n.Destination.Id, Name = n.Destination.Description }).ToList()
                     }

            ).ToList();
```